# On cleaning the projects, the R.java disappears from all projects

Tags: android

This is a bit weird.

I **cleaned my current project** and it started showing **error**. The self generated **R.java was gone**.
I **checked** the **xml files**. None of them was corrupt and **were good** as they should be.

I tried the same thing of **cleaning other projects** and **all** of them started **giving same error**.

After that I have **restarted everything, updated the sdk** and even **updated the debug.keystore file**. **None of this is helping**.

Still searching web for this. Don't know what should I try next.

Comment: Very interested in an answer to this question.  I usually just copy the whole project elsewhere.  I run the copy and it works.

Comment: It's bit bizarre though, I started installing the build tools and installation failed, but still the problem got solved. I am not quite sure which thing helped it getting rectified, nevertheless I think installation of the build tools was the last viable thing I tried in this case which made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have updated `SDK` so update your `ADT` version also. Please check that `Android Build-Tools` of `SDK` is installed or not, if not then Install it.  For update it follow some steps-- Go to **Window->Android SDK Manager**. Update and Install all tools (**![Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools,Android SDK Build-tools]**) which are in Tools folder.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually the creation of the resource file takes some time. Did you wait long enough for it to be generated?

Try to create a new workspace or rename the current one and see if that helps.
If so, import the old projects into the new workspace.

Also make sure to have the correct android library installed in the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: What do you mean by `the creation of the resource file`?  Does it get reset or deleted every time you clean the project?

Comment: if he's talking about R.java, then yes it gets deleted and created to add the new resources added in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Eclipse. Have you tried restarting it or refreshing project with f5?

Comment: yes...I am using eclipse..I have already tried all those things.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly occurs `when the IDE is unable to find the path` where the android SDK is installed. Check if the path set in your IDE is the correct path, try setting that manually by going to

```
 Window - Preferences - Android - SDK Location and setup SDK path.
```

then go to:

```
 Window > Preferences > General > Startup and shutdown: Check "Android development toolkit"
```

& restart eclipse from `File` menu.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Usually means something wrong with the XML. But if you don't find any problems with them, just restart Eclipse. It seems that restarting fixes a lot of issues with Eclipse.

Comment: I mentioned...I restarted everything...and that too not once.